# Java is hanging in Mac OS X Lion, and Javac runs more than 10 times slower than Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, javac

I have a very powerful Mac with latest OS X Lion and latest Apple 1.6 JDK. I just did a clean install after struggling with previous install.

The computer don't have problems, because I can run smoothly lot of heavy applications that don't use java (Avid Pro Tools, Gimp, 3D games...).

BUT, if I run a simple command like "mvn -version" or "java -version" or start the eclipse application, it hangs some seconds before answer... eclipse run fast, but hangs for a long time before the loading bar start.

A maven project that I build in my windows in 5 minutes, takes 1h in the mac.

If I create a simple HelloWorld class without any import and acall "javac HelloWorld.java", without set any extra classpath, it takes 20 seconds to compile.

---

I was about to install the Oracle Java 7. My intention is to keep both. But, while downloading I did something:

I was imagining that for every java call it hangs (for a javac that compile several classes, it hangs a lot), it looks like scanning for class path, or something like this. So I compared:

javac HelloWorld.java

to

sudo javac HelloWorld.java

The first today took almost 1 minute. The second one much less than one second.

I'm a admin user, but probably I have some other problem of permissions (maybe in some not related directory). I will post the solution here hope soon!

Comment: Why not Oracle's JDK?

Comment: It's working now. With Oracle JDK 7. I have no idea what's that problem 'cause I can reproduce it randomly, even with a just formatted OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your OS X Java installation.  First, I would try downloading and installing the latest Java 7 JDK from Oracle to see if that corrects your installation.